# Exposing interface types from EntityFramework's DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-ctp5

I was having a look at CTP5 of EntityFramework and the code first fluent interface. It looks very nice, but is there a way to make the DbContext expose only interface types and the in the fluent interface's model binder define a concrete implementation to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as of CTP5, EF Code First does not support interfaces and this feature is unlikely to be supported in the RTM that is targeted to be released this year.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What would you say is the best strategy for saving interface types? Convert to a dto?

Comment: No problem. I think your best bet is to define an abstract base class and place it in your DbContext to hold your objects, pretty much the same thing that you would have done if interfaces was supported.